# Create multi-language enum in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, enums, entity-framework-core

How to create a multi-language enum in EF Core ?

I added French name for enum property in `Description` attribute. I want to persist these values into the database and use it to show in ASP.NET UI lookup.

How to save/get this value to/from the database when doing EF Core migration?

```
    public enum Level
    {
        [Description("Basique")]
        Basic,
        [Description("Standard")]
        Standard,
        [Description("Prime")]
        Premium
    }
    
    public class SubscriptionLevel
    {
        public Level Name { get; set; }
        public decimal PricePerMonth { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfSimultaneousDevices { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You should store the integer value of enum to the database and display it to appropriate language in the code using resource file.

Comment: @Chetan then we have to manage enum in 3 place . Enum in code , resource file for UI , then DB for reporting and other stuff .

Comment: Is it _multi_ lingual or French, only? If the app is really multilingual then this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Fildor just French